# Single Equals in MYSQL

Tags: sql, mysql, conditional-statements, equals

I was wondering why MYSQL uses a single equals sign in conditional statements instead of the more typical two equals signs.  Is there a technical/historical reason for this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Hi, I was wondering why MYSQL uses a single equals sign in conditional statements instead of the more typical two equals signs. Is there a technical/historical reason for this? Thanks.

Comparison is much more common in `SQL` than assignment.

That's why `SQL` uses more short syntax to do more common things.

In classical `SQL`, comparison can be distinguished from assignment by context (assignment can be only in `SET` clause of an `UPDATE` statement), that's why one operator can be used for both operations.

In `MySQL`'s extension to `SQL`, assignment to a session variable is denoted by `:=`

Comment: SQL did not evolve from Ingres' QUEL. QUEL, although perhaps in some ways a better design, was supplanted by SQL.

Answer (score 7):

More like historical.

It's SQL. It has used a single equals sign for comparison since the early '70s.

Comment: It was developed by IBM in the '70s. It was originally named Structured English Query Language, so it's intended to be close to regular human language.

Answer (score 5):

**There is never a case for ambiguity in SQL.**

In the original *A Guide to the SQL Standard* by C.J.Date (1987 edition), `=` for assignment is only used in the `SET` clause of `UPDATE`. Everywhere else `=` is used it is used for comparison.

But in other languages, such as C/C++/C#/Java, `=` can be used as assignment but it also returns a value. So `a = b` means "set `a` equal to `b`, and return `a`" whereas `a == b` means "return `true` if `a` and `b` are equal". (This leads to a very common bug in C programs, because `if (a = b)` and `if (a == b)` are both valid, since the result doesn't have to be a bool.)

Some languages like JavaScript/ECMAScript also introduce `===` as a third type of comparison. In those languages, `==` means "convert to same type and compare" whereas `===` means "return `true` only if they are the same type and same value."