# Mysql function returning a value from a query

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-error-1064

i want to create a function which calculates a value using a query and I am having a problem returning the value:

Shortened, my query is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func01(value1 INT , monto DECIMAL (10,2)) RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
BEGIN
SET @var_name = 0;
select @var_name=if(value1 = 1,monto * table.divisa_dolar,table.monto *divisa_euro) from table where data_init = 1;
return @var_nam;
END
```

I get a SQL syntax error.

> SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Assuming these are all generic names (table will not be a good table name), the problem is you can't use == for comparison.  You are also missing some key syntax (DECLARE, SELECT INTO, etc.).

Change to this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION func01(value1 INT , monto DECIMAL (10,2))
RETURNS DECIMAL(10,2)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE var_name DECIMAL(10,2);
  SET var_name = 0;
  SELECT if(value1 = 1,monto *divisa_dolar,monto *divisa_euro) INTO var_name
    FROM table
    WHERE data_init = 1;
  RETURN var_name;
END
```

[MySQL Comparison Functions and Operators](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Related Question: [Single Equals in MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132686/single-equals-in-mysql)

Function Help: http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3569846/MySQL-Stored-Functions.htm

Comment: Yes, its a generic example :p. Make the correction but i am still getting the syntax errror. Thanks

Comment: You also need to add a DECLARE statement (see updated answer)

Comment: Added the declare statement, taked out the '@' and added a "select data into var". Its working. Thanks.