# mysql function that returns all addresses with character string when enter customer number

Tags: php, mysql, database, function

I have this mysql command create, but I am totally new, it gives me error of:

> Not allowed to return a result set from a function.

Here is how I create my sql function:

```
-> delimiter $$
-> create function myFunction(in_id INT)
-> returns VARCHAR(255)
-> begin
-> select concat(addr01, ',', addr02) as addfound from dtb_customer where customer_id = in_id;
-> return(addfound);
-> end$$
```

Please help me edit the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mysql function returning a value from a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940036/mysql-function-returning-a-value-from-a-query)

Answer (score 0):

You can't make Functions in **MySQL** from PHP.

May be that can be possible If Function is created in ***PHPMyAdmin*** and invoked somehow..... (I am not sure even this is possible)