# MySQL stored function to read column from row in table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

We need a function / stored procedure to return a column in a row in a table, where we pass the table, id field name, id and column to return.

We have a table which is an activity log with columns such as

- log_datetime  - the date/time the user did something
- log_table   - the table affected
- log_idcol   - the column in log_table that holds the id
- log_id      - the id of the row in log_table
- log_titlecol - the column in log_table which holds the 'title' of the
  item

So in a report/ MySql statement I need to be able to list the title which is held in the column name held in log_titlecol,  read from the table with the name in the log_table column, and id of whatever is in log_idcol.

so like

SELECT log_titlecol FROM log_table where log_idcol = log_id

where all the 'log_; parts are replaceable.  I can't see a way to do this in MySQL, so is there a way to do this in a stored procedure/function?

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE jokes (
  JokeID smallint(4) NOT NULL, **(autoincrement, unique)** 
  Title varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  Note text CHARACTER SET utf8
) 

CREATE TABLE idioms (
  IdiomID smallint(4) NOT NULL,  **(autoincrement, unique)**
  IdiomTitle varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  Note text CHARACTER SET utf8
) 

CREATE TABLE `log` (
  id smallint(4) NOT NULL, **(autoincrement, unique)**
  log_datetime datetime,
  log_table varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  log_idcol varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  log_id smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  log_titlecol varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
) 


INSERT INTO jokes (Title, Notes) 
VALUES ('Funny joke','This is note1')

INSERT INTO jokes (Title, Notes) 
VALUES ('Another Funny joke','This is another note')

INSERT INTO idioms (IdiomTitle, Notes) 
VALUES ('Bird in the hand','What this means..')

INSERT INTO jokes (Title, Notes) 
VALUES ('Another Funny joke','This is another note')

INSERT INTO log (log_datetime, log_table, log_idcol, log_id , log_titlecol) 
VALUES (now(), 'jokes','JokeID',1,'Title')

INSERT INTO log (log_datetime, log_table, log_idcol, log_id , log_titlecol) 
VALUES (now(), 'jokes','JokeID',2,'Title')

INSERT INTO log (log_datetime, log_table, log_idcol, log_id , log_titlecol) 
VALUES (now(), 'idioms','IdiomID',2,'IdiomTitle')
```

So now how can I have a report from log showing the date time and the Title column from the Jokes table, row id as in the log_id column? I need a function.

eg  SELECT log_datetime, log_table, log_id, GetTitle(log_table, log_idcol, log_id, log_titlecol) from log

Where GetTitle is a function which will return the column held in 'log_titlecol' form the table passed as log_table, from the row with an id (held in the log_idcol column) of log_id

So for example the output would show:

`2018-01-01 12:00    jokes   1   Funny Joke 
 2018-01-01 12:10    jokes   2   Another Funny joke
 2018-01-01 12:11    idioms  1   Bird in the hand`

I have tried

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Getcol(IN tab TEXT CHARSET utf8mb4, IN col TEXT CHARSET utf8mb4, IN idcol TEXT CHARSET utf8mb4, IN id INT(15), OUT outcol TEXT CHARSET utf8mb4)
 DETERMINISTIC
 COMMENT 'Return a column from any table'
 BEGIN
     SET @Expression = CONCAT('SELECT ', col,' INTO @outcol FROM ', tab, ' where ', idcol, ' = ', id); 
     PREPARE myquery FROM @Expression; 
     EXECUTE myquery; 
     SELECT @outcol;
 END
```

I can call this like
    `CALL GetCol('Jokes','Title','JokeID',1)`

And this works to return the Title column for ID 1, but I am cant seem to then put this call into a function

```
 CREATE FUNCTION getrowcol(tab TEXT, col TEXT, idcol TEXT, id INT) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4
     NO SQL
   COMMENT 'Return a column from any table'
   BEGIN
        DECLARE outvar TEXT;
        CALL GetCol(tab, col, idcol, id, @out1);
        SELECT @out1 INTO outvar;
        RETURN outvar;
   END
```

This returns blank. How can I return @out1?

This is essentially the same question (with no answer)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151328/dynamic-sql-stored-procedure-called-by-a-function

Comment: Have you try anything ?

Comment: I don't know where to start with a stored procedure which would take the passed parameters and form an SQL command and return the column

Comment: you should write function not procedure.

Comment: could you please add table and some insert query in your question ?

Comment: ok I have edited the OP

Comment: Which is the relational column between 2 tables ?

Comment: There is no relational column. as in the example, the column name to read the ID and the TITLE from must be passed parameters, and the name of the TABLE to read from (eg Jokes, Idioms, orders - anything) must also be a passed parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like,

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE demo(tab VARCHAR(50), tit VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN  
    SET @Expression = CONCAT('SELECT l.log_datetime, j.',tit,' FROM `log` l INNER JOIN ',tab,' j;');
    PREPARE myquery FROM @Expression;
    EXECUTE myquery;

END 
//

DELIMITER ;
```

**Call it like**

```
CALL demo('jokes', 'title')
```

from [Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: The table name 'jokes' for example here needs to be a variable, as does the column name title and the id column.

Comment: @Tr-evorH-awes I have updated the procedure, you can check now

Comment: Excellent -this is nearly what is needed - As you said though I need a FUNCTION which returns the title for one id, so demo('jokes','title','JokeID',1)  would return the title column of the jokes table, from the row with a jokeID of 1

Comment: Will that Id be the unique or not ? Please add some insert queries for both table and expected output too in your question

Comment: I have updated the OP. Yes ID will be unique in the given table in log_table.  So I would expect to get the single column where the title is held (whatever column name is in log_titlecol)

Comment: Why don't you add data for all tables ?

Comment: updated to try to make it clearer! :) The answer you gave above seems VERY good and near - just needs to return the title column

Comment: @Tr-evorH-awes What is your actual query without Function ?

Comment: I dont have one. I found it not possible to write one. So I needed a function. I feel you answer is near

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940036/mysql-function-returning-a-value-from-a-query  seems to also offer help.

Comment: I have updated the OP to include a procedure which works. But I cant now call that in a function (in a select statement)

Comment: You can no Call Dynamic procedure from function

Comment: Do you have any relationship between jokes and log table ?

Comment: no, only that a column in log table might store the name 'jokes' and the log_id column holds the id and log_idcol holds the id column name in table 'log_table'.  Maybe this is impossible

Comment: @Tr-evorH-awes Yes, Your requirement from query is impossible. right now