# MYSQL - Error Code: 1415. Not allowed to return a result set from a function. Stored function attempt

Tags: mysql

I am struggling in creating a stored function, as I am a complete beginner in databases. 
My aim is to turn this query into a stored function.

```
SELECT AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ShippedDate,OrderDate))) /86400 as OrdersAverage 
FROM orders;
```

The aim of this query is returning the average of difference between the dates of all the orders that  were placed when compared to the day they were shipped. 
When i tried, i got an error.

This was my definitely wrong stored function:

```
DELIMITER // 
CREATE FUNCTION OrderFulfilmentCycleTime()
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
        BEGIN
        SELECT AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(ShippedDate,OrderDate))) / 86400 
FROM    orders;
        END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Stored functions should only return one value. Your current query will return a "result set" hence the error.

Comment: Maybe the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940036/mysql-function-returning-a-value-from-a-query#4940148) will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MySQL function can't return a resultset i.e. the return from a SELECT statement.

In a MySQL function, use a `RETURN` statement to return a scalar value.

As an example:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION OrderFulfilmentCycleTime()
RETURNS DECIMAL(22,9)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   DECLARE ln_days DECIMAL(22,9);

   SELECT AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,o.orderdate,o.shippeddate))/86400
     FROM orders o
     INTO ln_days;

   RETURN ln_days;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

An example of calling the function:

```
SELECT OrderFulfilmentCycleTime();
```

---

If we need a MySQL stored program to return a resultset, we can define a PROCEDURE (rather than a FUNCTION).