# MySQL return true on label LIKE matched string

Tags: mysql, sql

Im facing some problems creating MySQL script.

The idea is to pass 2 variables to the function, one on them is string, which is used to search for 'LIKE' type of match in name or surename column, the second variable passed is foreign key as integer, which is meant to match an id column in table im trying to check the match.

Long story short i need to return true if name or surename is 'LIKE' passed string and the id of the exact row is like passed foreign key value in parameters. Stored function must return true or false at the end of execution.

My script looks like this so far :

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER FUNCTION `is_persona`(`searchq` varchar(100),`fk_key` int(11))
RETURNS integer
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SELECT
CASE WHEN name LIKE searchq THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS 'result',
CASE WHEN surename LIKE searchq THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'result'
FROM personas WHERE id = fk_key;
END;
```

And so far this script returns error `"1415 - Not allowed to return a result set from a function"`.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: 1) if the function is supposed to return True or False then why did you define it to return an INTEGER (i.e. a whole number)? Why not use BOOLEAN (or TinyInt(1) which it's a synonym for)? 2) You don't have a RETURN statement, and you don't have any variable which you could assign as the result. All you've done is run a query. You need to get the output of the query and assign it to a suitable variable and then return it.

Comment: Im just trying to make a function that was lost in a database i dont know well and looks like its trying to check if the given word truly is from the row with given id. The function in code is called like this : is_persona("%{$_SESSION['searchq']%", fk_persona) so i guess the session variable might be empty too, what to do in that case - i have no idea.

Comment: Well i cant assign BOOLEAN or BOOL as return type, but i can try to play around with tinyint, int was autogenerated when i clicked to create a function.

Comment: You need to be doing something like in this example where it gets a value from the table and assigns it to the return value: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940148/5947043

Comment: P.S. I'm a bit confused by `is_persona("%{$_SESSION['searchq']%", fk_persona)`...where are you using that? It looks like PHP rather than SQL. Does that point to a PHP function which then executes some SQL? It's unclear. But the error you're seeing doesn't relate to that, anyway.

Comment: Ahh yeah, sorry, forgot to mention. The script is generated in PHP and executed after all the variables are gathered into one long string, you know.. if statements in PHP which decide the need for additional options like if(isset($floor)){ $main_script.=" AND floor={$floor}"} (that was an example, nothing to do with my problem with mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you have to assign the `select` result into a variable. You can try something like below. *Use your `IF` conditions accordingly.*

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER FUNCTION is_persona(searchq varchar(100),`fk_key` int(11))
RETURNS varchar(20)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE MYOUTPUT1 varchar(20);
DECLARE MYOUTPUT2 varchar(20);
SELECT CASE WHEN name like concat('%',searchq,'%') THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS 'result',
       CASE WHEN surename like concat('%',searchq,'%')  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'result'
INTO MYOUTPUT1,MYOUTPUT2 --you are missing this part
FROM personas WHERE id = fk_key;

IF(MYOUTPUT1 =1 && MYOUTPUT2 =1 ) then
RETURN 'TRUE';
ELSE 
RETURN 'FALSE';
END IF;
END;
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6e940ae8ecd16853f89747d3b1a6906b)

**Update** for function with `boolean` return type

> MySQL does not have built-in Boolean type. However, it uses TINYINT(1) instead. To make it more convenient, MySQL provides BOOLEAN or BOOL as the synonym of TINYINT(1).

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER FUNCTION is_persona(searchq varchar(100),`fk_key` int(11))
RETURNS boolean
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE MYOUTPUT1 varchar(20);
DECLARE MYOUTPUT2 varchar(20);

SELECT CASE WHEN name like concat('%',searchq,'%') THEN 1 ELSE 0  END AS 'result',
       CASE WHEN surname like concat('%',searchq,'%')  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'result'
INTO MYOUTPUT1,MYOUTPUT2 
FROM personas WHERE id = fk_key;

RETURN IF((MYOUTPUT1 || MYOUTPUT2),true,false);

END;
```

[DEMO FOR BOOLEAN RETURNING FUNCTION](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4964d129a091c3f8fff6bfb79200ff49)

Comment: Hmm.. It kinda works, but there is one problem. I have row with id, name and surename, for example, id:9 ; name : Bob ; surename : Smith. The problem lies in output - i call the function like "SELECT("Bob", 9)" but it returns false, but the script so far looks clear and smooth. Any ideas ?

Comment: @MārisSkrīvelis  Because you are checking `Surname` also in your query with the value of `name`. Means you are checking `Bob` with surname as well which is false(because it is `*smith*`). So you have to pass one more parameter for `surname` or remove the `surname` check (`&& MYOUTPUT2 =1`).

Comment: Nope, turns out im smart enough to change the && sign to ||, because user can search for people by their name OR surename. So thanks to you all, now i can really feel the power of stackoverflow.

Comment: @MārisSkrīvelis..  That's a good idea as well :)  
And Welcome to Stackoverflow. Glad we could help !

Comment: the only problem now is that i need to return true or false as a boolean value not string. Since there is no BOOL or BOOLEAN, i have to figure out how to return 1 or 0, but that shouldnt be that hard i guess.

Comment: @MārisSkrīvelis, yes. I have created the same function with `boolean` return type here. [CHECK THIS OUT](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4964d129a091c3f8fff6bfb79200ff49) hope this is what you wanted. actually you can use boolean directly. It is the synonym of `TINYINT`.

Comment: @MārisSkrīvelis. i have updated the answer. check it out.

Comment: I already adjusted the code the way i needed. And it works like a charm. You just saved an salary system for one of the universities around the globe, great job buddy. i was struggling with this for few days until i picked stackoverflow as the last chance befrore my hopes die. Big thanks to you again.